# Multiple IF Statements only returning last value - PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I wrote a simple code that evaluates song ratings. We're trying to display stars based on the percentage that is returned.

The issue is that we have multiple IF statements that evaluate the percentage and return the correct amount of stars for the song. No matter what the song rating is, the IF statements keep returning 5 stars instead of returning the correct amount of stars.

We're using a flag to determine if a match was found in any of the IF statements.

```
function displayRatingStars() {
    /* Some Other Code */

    $likes = $json_data['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount'];
    $dislikes = $json_data['items'][0]['statistics']['dislikeCount'];
    $found = false; //flag to determine if match was found in any of the if statements

    $rating_total = $likes + $dislikes;
    $rating_percentage = number_format(($likes / $rating_total) * 100);

    /* no stars */  if ($rating_percentage <= 0) { echo '<div class="text-info padder m-t-sm text-sm"><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i></div>'; $found = true; }
    /* 1 star */    else if ($rating_percentage > 0 && $rating_percentage < 20) { echo '<div class="text-info padder m-t-sm text-sm"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i></div>'; $found = true; }
    /* 2 stars */   else if ($rating_percentage > 20 && $rating_percentage < 40) { echo '<div class="text-info padder m-t-sm text-sm"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i></div>'; $found = true; }
    /* 3 stars */   else if ($rating_percentage > 40 && $rating_percentage < 60) { echo '<div class="text-info padder m-t-sm text-sm"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i></div>'; $found = true; }
    /* 4 stars */   else if ($rating_percentage > 60 && $rating_percentage < 80) { echo '<div class="text-info padder m-t-sm text-sm"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i></div>'; $found = true; }
    /* 5 stars */   else if ($rating_percentage > 80) { echo '<div class="text-info padder m-t-sm text-sm"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></div>'; $found = true; }
    /* no match */  else { echo '<div class="text-info padder m-t-sm text-sm"><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i></div>'; $found = true; }
}
```

Is there a reason why this code is jumping directly to 5 stars instead of finding the correct match and ignoring the others?

I have a very similar function that uses IF statements to determine something else and it works fine. But this one does not.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fencepost errors:

```
if ($x < 20) { ... }
else if ($x > 20) { ... }
```

what if `$x` is EXACTLY 20? You fall through to the `else` clause.

Your comparison chain should be:

```
($rating_percentage > 0 && $rating_percentage <= 20)
($rating_percentage > 20 && $rating_percentage <= 40)
etc..
```

Note the `<=`.

Plus, `number_format()` returns a **STRING**. That string is intended to display numbers in human-friendly format. You're not using it in a human-friendly context. You're taking that formatted string and then shoving it through a bunch of integer comparisons.

While in your particular case it won't matter, consider this:

```
$x = 1000;
$y = number_format($x); // "1,000"

($x < 999) -> FALSE
($y < 999) -> TRUE, because 1,000 in numeric context becomes "1"
```

Comment: Gotcha. Good info. Thanks a lot, I'll make some changes and see if I can get it to work. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

[number_format()](http://php.net/number_format) function will return string so you shouldn't compare it to integers. That's first problem.

Next, that code is simply ugly and you are repeating a lot of things here. Try to refactor it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will remove the number_format() function. I have the statements all on one line to save space. But I will try to rework it so it's more artful and easier to follow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tested setting `$rating_percentage` to different values and it works. The issue you are having is first of all the `number_format()` function.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php - the function returns a string which can't be compared with the numbers in your `if` and `else if` statements.

Use `round(($likes / $rating_total) * 100, 0)` function instead of `number_format()`

Also note Marc B's answer, You have gaps in the value chain. Also, the final `else` will never come true if that is fixed. (`$rating_percentage` will always be in the range between <= 0, 1-4 star comparison and > 80)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the feedback! I'll try removing the number_format() function and see if I can get this thing working.

Comment: round() is working perfectly alongside what we need. Thanks again.